# can autoresizemask be applied on popovers

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

Again caught up in this orientation issue. I have a search screen where when a user taps on textfields a popover is displayed below that just like a dropdown menu but when the orienattion is changed to ladscape  popovers appear a bit to the left .

Can this be handled(apart from managing coordinates)

Thanks in advance

tried this piece of code

```
- (void)willRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

if (isPopOverNeedToBeManaged) {
    NSLog(@"Popover need to be managed");

    if (popOverSender) {
        NSLog(@"yes text field is there");
        if (popoverController) {
            [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];

        }
    }
}
```

}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{

  ```
      if (isPopOverNeedToBeManaged) {
          NSLog(@"Popover need to be managed");

          if (popOverSender) {
              NSLog(@"yes text field is there");
              if (popoverController) {


                  [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:txtDDDeliveryCenter.frame inView:subview permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];

              }
          }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch popover behavior in any Apples native application. You'll see that in response to device rotation popover should disappear before rotation animation and appear again on new appropriate place after it ends. So you should dismiss your popover and then popup it on new place with new coordinates.

Hope that'll help

Comment: thats the question how to do this exactly what APIs I can use to achieve this?

Comment: you should check before rotation (in viewControllers willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:) whether popover is showing or not (popoverVisible property in popover), save this value, dismiss popover (dismissPopoverAnimated:) and in didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method of your viewController call presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:
or presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated: according to whether it was visible before rotation or not